# why we need flink ? what's the different from springboot+database

Tags: spring-boot, apache-flink

I am learning flink. I am confused by the use scenario . Does we must use flink  , what's the different from a spring-boot(web framework) application ?
For example , I want count the page-view of a website in past 5 minuts . I can use flink's window to count . But I can recevie the request with springboot first and  then save to a time-series database  and  excute a sql to count it . What's the different between them  ?
In the official fraud-detection  use case (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/try-flink/datastream/) , I can  detect the suspicion transaction with  flink's state and window .  But I can  receive the transaction with a springboot application first  and  then  save the transaction to a time-series database ,  then  query all the transactions from the account to find the  suspicion . What's the different between them  ?
Is it about cluster scaling ? I think Springboot + kubernetes can dynamic-scale easily  too .
I tried to understand  flink's use case . And I want to know flink's benefit compare to traditional web+database stack .